Am unable to share files with my iPhone simulator as per Apple's instructions
Apple's docs on how to share files with the iPhone simulator (Xcode) are pretty straight forward:

Add files to Simulator
To add files to Simulator, select one or more files in Finder on your
Mac, then click the Share button. Select Simulator from the share
destination list. Choose the simulated device from the drop-down list.
Simulator opens the Files app, and lets you select where to save the
files.

But when I get to the point where the Simulator is supposed to open the Files app, nothing happens.
I've tried it with multiple simulators, and multiple iOS' but nothing ever happens.
Is there some sort of setting that I have to toggle to make this work?
